# F# Make Bar Chart with Winforms DataVisualization

Tags: winforms, charts, f#

I want to make a bar Chart with Winforms and F#. I have seen many other C# examples making a chart with `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` although when i try to open that library then it says then namespace is not defined.

Something as simple as this `let chart = new Chart()` doesn't work due to the namespace of the library not being defined i take it. Though I have seen people do this in C#. What is the correct way for F#?

Can someone be so kind to show me how to make a chart in F# and point me in the right direction of a bar Chart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to reference the correct assembly then you can `open` the namespace (equivalent of C# `using`) like this:

```
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting
```

However, before you go down this route, I would strongly recommend you use [FSharp.Charting](https://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/), which is a wrapper arround `DataVisualization.Charting` and much easier to work with in F#.

[Here is a snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/3b/title/Bar-chart-using-chart-controls) using `DataVisualization.Charting`

[Here is an example](https://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/BarAndColumnCharts.html) of using F# Charting

Comment: i dont understand what you mean by reference correct assembly?

Comment: Think i got it. 

#r "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll"
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting


is this right?

Comment: Yep, I was vague cause I wasn't sure if you were in a project or in an fsx script

Comment: nope i have only solved how to access the library. I still dont know how to make a chart() show and make a bar chart out of it

Comment: Well i would use it. If you can give me an example on how to make a bar chart. But the Questions Title here specificly says winforms.

Comment: Both suggestions work with winforms. I have included examples of both. One benefit of using F# Charting, is you will have better search results, documentation and examples because you wont have to filter out the C# examples.

Comment: I have tried copy pasting your snippet. The only thing that does is opening a window for a split second and then closing it again. Does it work in your end?

Comment: It does, not sure what you are seeing. If it makes you feel better, I spent 5 minutes trying to figure out why my code wasn't working, only to discover I had been using the "C# Interactive" pane (facepalm)

Comment: I added 

Application.Run form in the bottom. Now it works as charm for me aswell

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Stuart!

Comment: Always a pleasure =)