# Charts: chart.ChartAreas.add throws the exception: System.NotImplementedException

Tags: charts, reference, f#

I was checking out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41795086/f-make-bar-chart-with-winforms-datavisualization) question and tried to run the [snippet](http://www.fssnip.net/3b/title/Bar-chart-using-chart-controls) that was given in the answer. I did as they discussed in the comments and still got the exception "NotImplemented". I then proceeded to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297095(v=vs.100).aspx) tutorial, tried to run their code and got the same exeption. I noticed both places talking about correct referencing, but I don't know what they mean by it. I've narrowed it down and figured out, that the execption is thrown every time I try to use chart."something":

```
#r "System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.dll"

open System
open System.Drawing
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

let chart = new Chart(Dock = DockStyle.Fill)
let form = new Form(Visible = true, Width = 700, Height = 500)
//this throws the exception:
chart.ChartAreas.Add(new ChartArea("MainArea"))
```

Comment: The snippet you linked to still works for me. Are you running on Windows? AFAIK, the WinForms charting libraries are not supported on mono...

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu, but I do run it with mono... The .fsx I'm making has to be able to be ran with mono, what alternatives are there to the WinForms charting libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest looking at [F# Charting](https://fslab.org/FSharp.Charting/) if you are running this on Mono, as it has a [GTK package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Charting.Gtk) that works cross platform.

Comment: As this is an assignment I'm not sure I'm allowed to use libraries that are not already preinstalled.. Are there any preinstalled solutions or should I just juse f# charting and hope for the best?

Comment: Hope for the best.

Comment: I just read through the description of the assignment again, and this time it doesnt have to be ran with mono - what other compiler should I use then to make the snippet work?

Comment: If you are on linux then Mono is your best bet at the moment, .NET Core is getting there with F# (not officially supported though), but you'll find it hard to get a compatible version of this library today. Are you @Nulle btw? Cause you must be tired of me saying use F# Charting by now :-D

Comment: I will use F# Charting then, thank you very much!
- And no, but I did read through your conversations on his/her questions regarding the subject ^^ I won't rule out the posibility that we're working on the same assignment, however :-D

Comment: I would put money on it

Comment: I'm really new to all of this, how do I install the GTK package? I tried installing the .NET core to install nuget, and through nuget install the package. It is now installed but I can't access it when running a simple test program with mono. It really feels A LOT more complicated that it probably is... :i